# Get AppWorld link of my app programmatically

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

Is there any chance to get the app link(link from AppWorld) directly from the code?

It will be very helpful for me since I have more distributions of the same app and don't want to hard-code those links anymore. The link is used to open AppWorld at the app's page in order to update it.

I know that the application descriptor is edited after the app is published, and maybe the appWorld link is included into descriptor.

Comment: Are you asking if you can **detect** whether the app was installed through App World, or another app store, programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Id is a part of the application metadata. It has the name "RIM_APP_WORLD_ID".

```
// If you are targeting 4.3+, use this:
String myAppName = "My Amazing App"; //Name of your app
CodeModuleGroup group = CodeModuleGroupManager.load( myAppName );
String appid = group.getProperty("RIM_APP_WORLD_ID");
```

Check out this sample code [Getting Info from the App World](http://warodridev.blogspot.in/2011/12/blackberry-getting-info-from-app-world.html)